# Cómo importar un espacio de tablas de Postgresql 9.4

Tags: sql, postgresql

Estoy desarrollando un sistema embebido con Linux y Postgres 9.4.

El sistema embebido es básicamente un registrador de datos.

Tengo el espacio de tablas por defecto y una base de datos en la memoria interna. En esta guardo las configuraciones y demás datos necesarios para el funcionamiento del sistema.

En la tarjeta de memoria micro SD de 32GB he creado un nuevo espacio de tablas y una base de datos. En esta segunda base de datos registro todas las lecturas.

Todo funciona perfectamente. El problema viene cuando quiero mover la tarjeta micro SD a otro dispositivo embebido del mismo tipo y usar la base de datos que tiene ésta guardada. ¿Cómo "cargo" en Postgresql 9.4 el espacio de tablas que hay en la micro SD y su base datos?

No adjunto ningún código porque no tengo ninguno. Estoy leyendo la documentación y lo más parecido que encuentro es como crear backups y recuperarlas pero no es lo que necesito hacer. Si necesitáis más información o que describa algo más comentarlo. He intentado ser lo más descriptivo posible.

Un saludo a todos y muchas gracias desde ya por vuestra ayuda.

Comment: ¿Que SO estas utilizando?, como guardas o creas la base de datos de PostgreSQL en memoria interna y luego en la Micro SD.

Comment: Para crear la BBDD interna: `CREATE DATABASE mydatabase32 WITH OWNER pegasus TABLESPACE pg_default CONNECTION LIMIT -1; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE mydatabase32 TO pegasus;` Para crear la BBDD en la tarjeta SD: 1ro) `CREATE TABLESPACE externalcontainer OWNER pegaso LOCATION '/media/sdcard/'` 2do) `CREATE DATABASE sdcarddatabase WITH OWNER pegaso ENCODING 'UTF8' TABLESPACE externalcontainer LC_COLLATE 'es_ES.UTF-8' LC_CTYPE 'es_ES.UTF-8' CONNECTION LIMIT -1; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE sdcarddatabase TO pegaso;`

Comment: No entiendo exactamente a que te refieres con "Tengo el espacio de tablas por defecto", bueno aquí la aclaración es que las tablas en PostgreSQL no tienen como tal una configuración de espacio, tomarán el disponible del medio de almacenamiento según vayan creciendo, si es diferente a eso podrías explicarme a que te refieres?. Por otra parte, a ver si entiendo, esa base de datos que tienes en la SD la quieres mover a otro dispositivo  y este dispositivo automáticamente la cargue? o es otra cosa la que quieres hacer. Sludos!

Comment: @DrakoRod a espacio de tablas por defecto me refiero única y exclusivamente a *”TABLESPACE **pg_default**”*. Cómo se puede ver en el código SQL de creación de la BBDD interna. Este espacio de tablas se crea por defecto con toda instalación de PostgreSQL sin que el usuario tenga que hacerlo. Y efectivamente,  quiero mover la tarjeta micro SD a otro dispositivo embebido del mismo tipo y usar la base de datos que tiene ésta guardada. Obviamente veo que no se puede hacer esto de forma automática, y quiero saber qué pasos he de dar para poder usarla.

Answer (score 0):

Después de todo lo comentando contesto cintando el problema:

> ... El problema viene cuando quiero mover la
>   tarjeta micro SD a otro dispositivo embebido del mismo tipo y usar la
>   base de datos que tiene ésta guardada. ¿Cómo "cargo" en Postgresql 9.4
>   el espacio de tablas que hay en la micro SD y su base datos?

Ese proceso no lo podrás hacer en caliente o en su caso automáticamente (mover la tarjeta mientras el servidor PostgreSQL este prendido, hacia otro puerto y/o dispositivo), ya que todas las tablas trabajan con páginas, y estas páginas se encuentran en constante modificación cuando el servidor esta prendido, si mueves estás tablas a otra ubicación mientras el servidor sigue prendido te causará corrupción silenciosa datos.

Si quieres hacer ese proceso tendrás que hacerlo en "frío", antes de todo tienes que tener en cuenta los siguientes puntos:

- Ubicación del directorio por default (mejor identificado como PGDATA por ejemmplo: /var/lib/postgresql/10/data todo el contenido del diretorio data)
- Ubicación y punto de montaje del tablespace.

Ahora después de ello deberás de seguirestos pasos:

1. Apaga el Servidor PostgreSQL Origen y el PostgreSQL destino
2. Copia el Directorio PGDATA (osea el default) a el dispositivo destino sobre la misma ruta que lo tienes en el dispositivo origen (por ejemplo: /var/lib/postgresql/10/data)
3. Monta la unidad SD dentro del nuevo dispostivo, asegúrate que el punto de montaje es exactamente el mismo. Osea la misma ruta: '/media/sdcard/' cuando creaste el tablespace en el otro
4. Dentro del punto de montaje del SD debe de existir el directorio del tablespace algo nombrado como esto: PG_9.4_201707211 que justamente es la dirección.
5. Una vez hecho esto Inicia el Servidor Destino, y prueba.

Cualquier duda lo checamos en los comentarios.

Saludos!

Comment: Por lo que leo entiendo que para usar la BBDD externa (la que está en la tarjeta SD) en otro dispositivo ***también*** he de copiar a nivel ficheros la parte interna del sistema de PostgreSQL. ¿He entendido bien? ¿No hay manera de hacerlo sin “clonar” ambas bases de datos? Yo estaba buscando el registro o los datos que le dicen al motor de PostgreSQL cual es el identificador y/o ruta al “tablespace” que está en la SD. Suponía que importando esta información en el nuevo dispositivo podría usar la SD con todo su contenido.

Comment: No exactamente, cuando generas un tablespace este se guarda dentro de los catalogos de sistema con la ruta, entonces cuando migras ese tablespace, sin hacer un clonado de la base default (que contiene los catalogos de sistema), no reconocerá que tablas y que estructura tienen aunque estas existan dentro del tablespace, para ello mejor utiliza un backup y cargarlo, te creará el tablespace y copiará los datos de 0, sin necesidad de hacer todo el proceso que te dije .